# Is this index pertinent with TimescaleDB?

Tags: postgresql-11, timescaledb

I have a question concerning indexes with timescaleDB

We have a table with the following columns:

| timestamp | id | value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Where id represent a measurement. For example : Room temperature in a specific location

Currently we have 2 indexes `(id, timestamp DESC)` and the default `(timestamp DESC)`

We have basically two type of query :

1. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'aaa' AND timestamp BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>`
2. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', ...) AND timestamp BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>`

It seems the index 1 is very good for query 1.

For query 2 the number of id can get up to almost 200. In this case could it be pertinent to add an index on `(timestamp DESC, id)` ?

And maybe remove the default `(timestamp DESC)` ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, the existing index on `(id, timestamp DESC)` should be better than `(timestamp DESC, id)`, since the first one is expected to select on `id` first and then on `timestamp`. The opposite index might be better if just few rows satisfy the query condition on `timestamp`, i.e., `timestamp BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>`.

I highly recommend to run [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) on your queries and understand how existing indexes are used in the query plans.

If you keep index on `(id, timestamp DESC)`, then it might good idea to keep the default index on `(timestamp DESC)`.

Timescale wrote a [blogpost about using composite indexes](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/), which you might want to check.